# Links on Auth Site are Appending Prod Targethostname URL

Tags: sxa

I have two Site groupings set up in Sitecore - Test Auth and Test Prod. Test Auth has a site URL of test1-sc10-auth.com, while Test Prod has a site URL of test1-sc10.com.

[image: auth]

[image: prod]

However, whenever I click on a search link on the Test Auth site, it appends the Test Prod Targethostname URL at the end of the link, resulting in an incorrect URL structure (for example, https://test1-sc10-auth.comhttps//test1-sc10.com/search-results#e=0&q=news). The only way I have been able to resolve this issue is by unticking the 'Enable Preview' option in both Test Auth and Test Prod.

[image]

Can anyone suggest what may be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35625/incorrect-canonical-url-in-sitecore-sxa-multisite-domain-name-gets-appended-tw/35626#35626

Answer (score 0):

It looks like two `Site Groupings` are valid for same environment.

To identify this issue you can check `SXA Site Manager`.

If you have CM and CD servers, it is a good idea to use `Valid for Environment` field where you could specify your environment variable matching `XA.Foundation.Multisite.Environment`setting like `ContentManagement` or `ContentDelivery`.

More details below :

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/manage-multiple-sites-with-the-sxa-site-manager.html

or

https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/setting-up-multiple-hosts-sitecore-sxa-site

Answer (score 0):

There are several settings in `Sitecore.config` that help to configure proper site resolving logic. You can check the setting called `Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentSite`. To make sure that items are opened in context of correct site, you must set the `Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentSite` setting to `true` that should be checked to true.

Other than that you should also check if the sites are resolving properly in `SXA site manager`. If not, you should make it resolve.

Here is a good article that you can use to set up multiple hosts for a Sitecore SXA site and verify with your solution if you are missing something.

[Setting Up Multiple Hosts For A Sitecore SXA Site](https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/setting-up-multiple-hosts-sitecore-sxa-site)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking `Sitecore.XA.SitesToResolveAfterSxa.config` configuration. I suspect the issue could be due to Site Resolving.

When `SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext` method is called from `SxaSiteResolver`, a `SxaSiteProvider` gets resolved in `SiteManager` and `GetSites()` method returns all the SXA sites by parsing the items located at `/sitecore/content/[Tenant]/[Site]/Settings/Site Grouping/*` based on template `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Site`

If your SXA sites are not resolving correctly, because of compatibility with other modules, you can mark other sites to be resolved before or after SXA sites by adding the site name and `resolve="before"` or `resolve="after"` to the `Sitecore.XA.SitesToResolveAfterSxa.config` (App_Config\Modules\SXA\z.Foundation.Overrides)

Hope it helps!