# Insert Link SXA Current Site Item is not displaying

Tags: sxa

We have maintained `SXA` multisite with the same tenant. In `Settings`, we have selected the `"Linkable Site with a tenant"` option in the Link settings.

```
Site A
Site B
```

In Site A, from any CTA link if I try to select the `insert link` option `Site A` home and child items are not displaying and in Site B home and child items are displaying.

Why the Site A home and child item is not displaying?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in your data template, the `Source` property of your `GeneralLink` field is set to `query:$linkableHomes`

Next make sure that in your `/sitecore/Content/<Tenant>/<Site>/Setting` item you have the `Link Settings` option set to `All linkable sites` or `Linkable sites in site collection`. By default this will be `Itself only`

[image]

Along with the settings mentioned by Vikrant, that should enable the linkable sites option for you.

Reference: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/adjust-link-settings-to-enable-cross-site-linking.html

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on combination of following settings of both sites. You may want to check those for Site A and B and that should give you clue.

- `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site A/Settings/Site Grouping/Your-Site-Definition-Item` >> `Linkable site` field
- `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site A/Settings` >> `Link Settings` field

Mark `Site A` as `Linkable Site` and that should help.

Comment: In the Site grouping Linable Site field is already checked.

Comment: do you have multiple site definition items ?

Comment: yes, I have mutiple

Comment: Give this a try then. Arrange definition items in such a way that your active definition item is at first position. Somehow this sequence made a difference in my case in past. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35625/incorrect-canonical-url-in-sitecore-sxa-multisite-domain-name-gets-appended-tw

Comment: Thanks Vikrant, After the rearrangement it is working now.